How to set new local address and port to loopback on web browser
For Window, I use the loopback address is http://127.0.0.1:8080/ to go to server.  I saw on forum that Raspberry Pi need 0.0.0.0 to listen to port.  If I use http://127.0.0.1:8080/ or http://localhost/, it shows 127.0.0.1 refused to connect..  But for some reason, I cannot use http://0.0.0.0/ for loopback and open web browser unless it is https.  Is it possible to create a new local address and port (such as 127.0.0.2:8080) or create a new port on 127.0.0.1 for localhost and open in web browser?



Welcome. The 0.0.0.0 address is not in any way Pi or linux specific, it means exactly the same thing on Windows, as do all aspects of IP addressing.  The obvious issue here, evident from your netstat and nmap output, is there is no http server (or anything else) running on 8080.   Note that how to  operate a web server on linux is off-topic here, such questions belong on Unix & Linux. Please take the tour to understand better how the site works.

@goldilocks Actually what I facing is I want to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8080.  However it shows 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. on bowser.  I search through forum that if using Raspberry Pi, it should use 0.0.0.0 as loopback.  I saw all people with this problem is on Raspberry Pi and I thought it is Raspberry Pi problem.  I know there is no port 8080 so I would like to ask is there a way to open port 8080 for 127.0.0.1. I have tried on my Window and and it works so I think it isn't related to Window.

open port 8080 for 127.0.0.1 open it for WHAT? if something listened on 127.0.0.1:8080 then you can connect to it. As it is, there is nothing listening on that port. What did you expect on that port?

"I want to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080. However it shows 127.0.0.1 refused to connect" -> Yes, because again:  there is no http server (or anything else) running on 8080. "is there a way to open port 8080 for 127.0.0.1"  -> Yes, you start a server of some sort which opens the port and listens on it.  An "open port" with no server on it is sometimes used in a firewall context to refer to a port that is not blocked by the firewall; if there is no firewall then it can only refer to a port with an active, listening server.

You did not mention any firewall, and there is obviously no server running.  "I have tried on my Window and and it works" -> You have tried what? Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080?  If it works, that is because you have a web server running.   That is the entire issue here:  The difference is on the windows box you have a web server installed and listening on port 8080, whereas on the Pi you have nothing.  But again, these are basic networking concepts and the same would be true if it were simply another Windows machine or an iphone or any other kind of computer with IP network access.
